# nodejs version on EPEL repository

Tags: centos, yum, node.js

Current stable [node.js](https://nodejs.org/) version is **v0.12.2**. I just run `yum update` on my machine and it updated node to **v0.10.36**.

Why is my EPEL repo version so old compared to current stable one? Can I update node to latest version through yum or do I have to compile it myself?

I have CentOS 6.6

Comment: 0.10.36 dates to January 26. Is that so terribly old as to be unusable? Remember that EL and EPEL are meant to be _stable_.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, at the time I'm checking the nodejs.org website, the current stable release is at version 5.1.0. https://nodejs.org/dist/v5.1.0/ ; I think we can all agree that the version on EPEL is significantly outdated, like, 4 major stable revisions outdated. :/

Comment: @JesúsZazueta It's a little difficult for anyone to keep up when a framework has 4 major stable revisions in less than a year! That alone would make me not want to work with node.js (but I have other reasons too).

Comment: @MichaelHampton ah, you're right. It's a bit frightening how fast is the JavaScript app ecosystem moving. Even the node & io.js versions themselves look a bit weird. Oh well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RHEL 6 was [released](https://access.redhat.com/articles/3078) in 2010 and one of the consequences of choosing an **enterprise** distribution with long term support cycles is you'll end up with seeming old versions of software, a trade-off for stability and better support for third-party software.

(**Note:** an old version do not equate to insecure, read up on [**backporting**](https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting) of security updates.)

Typically if you need something more recent you should look for a the next major release i.e. RHEL 7.

You might get more recent supported versions of certain software in older Red Hat Enterprise Linux releases by subscribing to the  [**Software Collections**](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Software_Collections/2-Beta/html/2.0_Release_Notes/chap-RHSCL.html#sect-RHSCL-About) channel.

Node.js  is part of the SC channel currently supported as release 0.10 so that seems about correct.

Comment: RHEL / CentOS 7 are also on node.js 0.10.X

Answer (score 1):

Regarding why EPEL does not contain the latest versions, taken from the [EPEL Guidelines and Policies](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/GuidelinesAndPolicies#Why_not_a_rolling_release_with_latest_packages_like_what_was_in_Fedora_Extras.3F):

> **Why not a rolling release with latest packages like what was in Fedora
>   Extras?**
>
> Why should we? That would be what Fedora Extras did and worked
>   and works well for it -- but that's mainly because Fedora (Core) has
>   lots of updates and a nearly rolling-release scheme/quick release
>   cycle, too. But the Enterprise Linux we build against is much more
>   careful with updates and has longer life-cycle; thus we should do the
>   same for EPEL, as most users will properly prefer it that way, as they
>   chose a stable distro for some reasons -- if they want the latest
>   packages they might have chosen Fedora.
>
> Sure, there are lots of areas where having a mix of a stable base and
>   a set of quite new packages on top of it is wanted. *Maybe* the EPEL
>   project will provide a solution (in parallel to the carefully updated
>   repository!) for those cases in the long term, but not for the start.
>   There are already third party repositories out there that provide
>   something in this direction, so users might be served by them already.
>
> Further: A rolling release scheme like Fedora Extras did is not
>   possible for many EPEL packages for another reason, new packages often
>   require new versions of certain core libraries. This will cause
>   problems in EPEL because we won't be able to provide updated libs as
>   it would replace libraries in the core OS.
>
> Example: This document was written round about when RHEL5 got
>   released; many packages that get build for RHEL5 can't be build for
>   RHEL4 at this point of time already, as the RHEL4-gtk2-Package is two
>   years old and is too old for many current applications, as they depend
>   on a newer gtk2. So if even if we would try to have a rolling scheme
>   with quite new package we'd fail, as we can't build a bunch of package
>   due to this dependencies on libs; in the end we would have a repo with
>   some quite new packages while others are still quite old. That mix
>   wouldn't make either of the "latest versions" or "careful updates
>   only" sides happy; so we try to target the "careful updates only"
>   sides. Remember, EPEL's support and updates cycle is much longer then
>   Fedora's.